# Using CSS3 animations in WordPress child theme

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, css

I am trying to use the CSS3 animation cheatsheet by justinaguilar in a WordPress cild theme that I've created. This is my first child theme, as I am trying to get to grips with CSS, stylesheets etc.

So I have included the animations.css in the header so it loads properly, I then have created an object in my style.css,

```
#object {
background: url('../marias_child/images/logo_3redbags.png') no-repeat;
width: 500px;
height: 1500px;
position: relative;
visibility: visible;
}
```

I then use a div to include the object in a WordPress page in the editor and call the necessary class to animate it, like so:

```
<div id="object" class="tossing">
```

All is fine up to now, what I am trying to do next is to target an existing object, predefined in my theme a special offer widget and apply animation to that. Is this something I do in the style.css? If so, how would I try it? I have found the selector .widget.offer-widget.bs but I have no understanding of how to animate it using the stylesheet.

It must be very straightforward but I am still learning.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add your "animation" in the child theme's style.css and override the existing class of the widget with your style.
Use the firebug extension for firefox to check what class you want to change.

The example code for your style.css in your child theme will be:

```
.widgetclass{
background: url('../marias_child/images/logo_3redbags.png') no-repeat;
width: 500px;
height: 1500px;
position: relative;enter code here
visibility: visible;
}
```

It might be using class or id.

Comment: That is great. So I target the widgetclass in the style.css but what happens with the "enter code here" part that you describe. Remember I have to use an animation class from the css cheat sheet in animation.css "on" that object. This part I still don't understand. How do I animate say using "tossing"? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to see CSS animations for that. Google it and see, then add the animations.